# React-navigation installation error(following official docs). Unable to resolve module @react-navigation/native-stack

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

There are a bunch of questions already covering this exact error, but I've been through all of them, and so far none of the answers have worked for me. Platform is MacOS

### Here is the error:

[image]

### Steps to reproduce

(Following official React Navigation docs https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started/):

1. Create a new expo managed app

- `expo init my-app`

2. Navigate to directory
3. Start the app

- `expo start`
- **** At this point everything starts and works correctly ****

4. Install reactnavigation(follow official docs https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started/ )

- `yarn add @react-navigation/native`

5. Install dependencies

- `expo install react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context`

6. Wrap the code with a Navigation container (per the docs)
7. Start the app

- `expo start`
- **** App no longer works. Fails with the error I posted earlier ****

### Things I've tried that haven't worked

1. The instructions that the error message provides (though I skip step 1, as I don't have watchman watches installed). Main thing here that I would expect to work is the deletion of `node_modules` and `yarn.lock`, but no luck :(. Same with deleting cache
2. using `yarn add` to add the dependencies instead of `expo install`
3. using npm to install everything
4. updating expo-sdk (I'm already on latest)
5. reinstalling everything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I actually was able to answer my own question in the process of writing it. I often do this, as I make sure to spend several hours trying to debug in the process of writing the question and making sure I've covered everything I can think to try.

Not sure of official self answer etiquette, but this was a pretty frustrating error for me, so I figure I'll post what worked for me here in case it can help anyone else in the future.

Answer:
The issue for me had nothing to do with the code or app itself, but rather the IOS simulator. Force quitting the simulator and restarting resolved the error. It seems that simply ctrl^c -> expo start -> i -> r is not enough to clear the internal state of the simulator.

There was actually even a clue in the error message itself, but I missed it because the error looked so similar to the one I was expecting. The clue was in the name of the module it was unable to resolve "@react-navigation/native-stack". In my reproduction steps, I was only using the NavigationContainer, as I was trying to get that working before installing any of the Navigators and trying to use those.

Why was it trying to resolve the native-stack navigator? I'm not 100% sure, but my guess is that there was some kind of cache in the simulator that wasn't being cleared properly. Why do I think that?

This problem started with me trying to use a native-stack navigator in another app I'm working on. I quickly ran into this error, and figured the best way to debug would be to spin up a brand new blank app and try to get ReactNavigation working in there. I started with just navigation package and NavigationContainer itself, and once I couldn't even get that working, I assumed the problem was with the base react-navigation package installation. I failed to notice that it was still trying to resolve that native-stack navigator.